# How to configure apache http client v3.0 for web application (multithreading)

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, http, jakarta-ee

I use apache http client (version 3.0 because we have java 1.4 and cannot change it) in web application. 
I have component (class) that is used for POST requests to the server, and this component is used on JSP pages, i.e. from different threads.

So I  create client only once in some init() method of that component:

```
  HttpClient client =
            new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager());
  client.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(proxyHost, proxyPortInt.intValue());
  HttpState state = new HttpState();
  state.setProxyCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPortInt.intValue()),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, userpassword));
  client.setState(state);
```

and then use it in method that can be accesses in several threads:

```
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(urlStr);
method.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(requestStr));
method.setRequestHeader("Host", "the_same_host_every_time ");
method.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");
method.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(requestStr.length()));
InputStream responseStream = null;
try {
  int resultCode = client.executeMethod(method);
  responseStream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
...
```

This app makes requests to the same host every time. MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager has the following properties:

1. DEFAULT_MAX_HOST_CONNECTIONS 
         The default maximum number of connections allowed per host (Per RFC 2616 section 8.1.4, this value defaults to 2.)
2. DEFAULT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS 
         The default maximum number of connections allowed overall

I didn't change them yet. Does this mean that my app will be able to do max 2 request at the same time (because all they are to the same host)? Why default value is 2? Should I change DEFAULT_MAX_HOST_CONNECTIONS value (there are a lot of users for this application that can access JSP simultaneously). What's about DEFAULT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, is this parameter important for my application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "should I change", "is it important for my app"? only you can know what's important for you. Try it out, see if it makes things better for you.

Comment: We cannot try, we provide our customer only with several components but don't have the full application to test. I just try to understand what this parameters mean and what are the best practices.

Comment: If you cannot upgrade from 1.4, you can use retroweaver to transform your application from a newer version to 1.4.

Comment: wow, you can't test your code before shipping it to your customer? that's pretty scary. The descriptions of the parameters are pretty explicit, there's nothing tricky in there. Just create a dummy app that does the same type of thing and change the params to see how they work. But not testing this before shipping...

Comment: What for? The question is about apache http client.

Comment: Mat, of course we test it using dummy application. I meant that we cannot test it under real load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar scenario some time ago and the key points to multi-threaded use were

- using a `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` (you already do)
- **NOT** sharing instances of `HttpMethod` (e. g. `GetMethod`) and `HttpState` between threads

`HttpState` encapsulates the conversational state between subsequent requests including the session ID (if any). So when trying to do concurrent requests to some kind of "backend" (e. g. a web site) you do not want to share it between threads in order not to mix up sessions and get unpredictable results.

The reference documentation has a [chapter on threading](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/threading.html) and also a section called ["Concurrent execution of HTTP Methods"](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/performance.html#Concurrent_execution_of_HTTP_methods). The earlier explains the configuration parameters you mention, the latter multi-threaded use in general.